# How to live update large amounts of data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am working on a stock app in flutter and I need to have the stock data update on its own really quickly without having to scroll and refresh. What's the best way to do this, without crashing anything? I am using yahoo finance api from rapid api.

Comment: I'm thinking of using a MultiNotifierProvider() widget. Would that be sufficient for not crashing the app or is there another widget that will work with "live updates" better?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `StreamBuilder` it is better for continuous update data.
also, you can refer to this for more about StreamBuilder : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html